# SQL question dealing with odd numbers dont work

Tags: sql

i am a new learner to SQL and here's the question i am trying to solve:

Show patient_id, attending_doctor_id, and diagnosis for admissions that match one of the two criteria:

1. patient_id is an odd number and attending_doctor_id is either 1, 5, or 19.
2. attending_doctor_id contains a 2 and the length of patient_id is 3 characters.

```
    SELECT 
        patient_id, 
        attending_doctor_id, 
        diagnosis 
    FROM 
        admissions
    WHERE 
        ((patient_id like '%1' or 
        patient_id like '%3' or 
        patient_id like '%5' or 
        patient_id like '%7' or 
        patient_id like '%9') and 
        attending_doctor_id in (1,5,19))
    or 
        (attending_doctor_id like '%2%' and 
        patient_id like '%___%');
```

i understand my code isn't the most direct way however logically it should work? the correct solution returns around 700 entries, my code returned 2000 entries, the first 100 match with that of the correct solution. where did i do wrong?

Comment: patient_id like '%___%' will match any length id.

Comment: oh really, even i specifically used three underscores? i was under the impression you can use underscores to indicate number of characters.

Comment: @strattonn thank you!  i changed patient_id like '%___%' to len(patient_id) is 3. and all worked. thank you for the insights

Comment: the % matches any string. If your patient_id is always numeric patient_id < 999 would be better than len.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite new on SQL too, hope i can help you.
First thing is that you should simplify your "WHERE" query. This is normally making query complex and failed to return accurate result.

So, for first criteria:
patient_id is an odd number and attending_doctor_id is either 1, 5, or 19.

a) In maths, x % 2 = 1 denoted that x must be an odd number.

b) attending_doctor_id IN (1,5,19) returns any result of the matched selections 1,5,19

```
SELECT patient_id, attending_doctor_id, diagnosis
FROM admissions
WHERE patient_id % 2 = 1
AND attending_doctor_id IN (1, 5, 19);
```

for second criteria:
attending_doctor_id contains a 2 and the length of patient_id is 3 characters.

a) use LIKE "%2%" to return result with "2" in any position

b) use LENGTH(patient_id)= 3 to return result with 3 characters length

```
SELECT patient_id, attending_doctor_id, diagnosis
FROM admissions
WHERE attending_doctor_id LIKE '%2%'
AND LENGTH(patient_id) = 3;
```

Finally, use UNION to join all this query to make the returned result in one list.

```
SELECT patient_id, attending_doctor_id, diagnosis
FROM admissions
WHERE patient_id % 2 = 1
AND attending_doctor_id IN (1, 5, 19);
UNION
SELECT patient_id, attending_doctor_id, diagnosis
FROM admissions
WHERE attending_doctor_id LIKE '%2%'
AND LENGTH(patient_id) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select patient_id, attending_doctor_id, diagnosis from admissions 
where (mod(patient_id,2) != 0 and attending_doctor_id in (1,5,19)) or
( attending_doctor_id like '%2%' and len((patient_id)) = 3);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).